# why v-for on array of objects within an object, doesn't update even with :key?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm iterating through an array within an object. When I update an object in the array, the data updates, but, the UI doesn't

Data looks like this

```
projectConfig = {
   files: [
      lang: "ar-eg",
      paths: ["/Users/omarabdelhady/Desktop/Others/test/i18n/ar-eg.json"]
   ]
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="col-12 files-box">
    <div v-for="(file, index) in projectConfig.files" :key="file.lang">
        <bdi>Lang : {{file.lang}}</bdi>
         <div>
           Files :
             <ul class="col-12 app-list">
                <li v-for="(path, i) in file.paths" :key="path">
                   {{getFileNameFromPath(path)}}
                      <i class="i-bin"
                         @click="deleteLang(i, index)">
                      </i>
                </li>
             </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

delete method

```
  deleteLang(pathIndex, fileIndex) {
    this.projectConfig.files[fileIndex].paths.splice(pathIndex, 1);
     if(this.projectConfig.files[fileIndex].paths.length === 0) {
       this.projectConfig.files.splice(fileIndex, 1);
     }
   }
```

I use the :key for v-for to detect changes, didn't work
I tried this.$forceUpdate(), worked, but I think it is not the best solution

-- update
actually the data looks like this

```
projectConfig = {
   files: [{
      lang: "ar-eg",
      paths: ["/Users/omarabdelhady/Desktop/Others/test/i18n/ar-eg.json"]
   }]
}
```

plus I'm using typescript

Comment: The only problem I see is that you forgot to encapsulate the element in `files` as an object. I tried your code in a fiddle (with the fix) and it worked just fine. Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/9dxeh671/

Comment: can you please point out to the change, I don't see what did you do?

Comment: I simply encapsulated your files with object notation like this: `files: [{
      lang: "ar-eg",
      paths: ["/Users/omarabdelhady/Desktop/Others/test/i18n/ar-eg.json"]
   }]`

Comment: that's already how my data looks like I will update it, but still doesn't work, I will also make it clear that I'm using typescript

Comment: I agree with @Ayrton. The code works for me too. Maybe you should share a JSFiddle, so that we can check what's wrong with your code.

Comment: actually i'm not able to write it no jsfiddle, i don't know how to write it using typescript, i can provide the whole component script code if that may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm **guessing** that the problem is that the reactivity is not setup on component initialization. Either the data is not available initially, or there are too many nested objects and arrays.

looking at this nested object...
`projectConfig.files[i].paths[j]`

that is a string in an array in an object in an array in an object.

if the array is empty when the component is initiated, the reactivity is not added. You can try using `slice` and `$set` to trigger the reactivity.

Comment: Yes, that's correct the data was not initially there, did not know that the data has to be initialized so i had to construct the data with initial values in all levels for it to work,

Comment: constructor() {
        this.projectName = '';
        this.projectDir = '';
        this.files = [
            {lang: '', paths: []}
        ]
    }

this is what I did, you may update your answer rather than putting it in the question itself